# Facebook application "if empty session" not working, how can I fix it?

Tags: php, facebook, try-catch, fbml

This is the code I am using to hopefully create a very simple app on facebook to say "Hello (name)" however I get the error "An error occoured".

```
<?php

require "facebook.php";

// create application instance
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => '********************************',
'secret' => '********************************',
'cookie' => true,
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();

if (!empty($session)) {
        try {
            $uid = $facebook->getUser();
            $user = $facebook->api('/me');
        } catch (exception $e) {}

    if (!empty($user))
    {
        if($_GET['installed']=='1') {
            header("Location: http://apps.facebook.com/gamerimg/");
        }

        echo "Hello ".$user['first_name'];
    } else {
        die("An error occoured!");
    }
} else {

    $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    echo "<a href='".$url."'>Click here</a> to add the GamerImg Facebook application.";

}

?>
```

I am very new to fbml so I have no idea what to do! How can I fix it?!

It's probably something to do with this line: `$user = $facebook->api('/me');`

Comment: Can you display the exception? `catch (exception $e) { print_r($e); }`

Comment: Errr... yep.. that: http://pastebin.com/eSnSKCvi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your Facebook calls are throwing an exception, but you catch the exception and keep going. Normally you'd put the die call inside the catch block, and the if block inside the try block.

And if you put the die call inside the try block, I'd change it to `die("An error occurred! ".$e->getMessage());` so you can see what the error message is.

Comment: "Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl" That looks a bit easier to understand! What does it mean....?

Comment: The libcurl library on your system wasn't compiled with HTTPS support. Contact your system administrator and get them to recompile with libcurl with HTTPS support.

Comment: it's becasue I use free hosting... is there any way around it?

Comment: Get a better host?

You might be able to hack the Facebook library to not use HTTPS, but I don't know if Facebook would even support that.